# Unity storing Functions in Graph View

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a little stuck on this specific problem I have with the graph view in unity. I've successfully implemented a dialogue system with multiple choices, playing animations depending on the node and branching in directions. One final data type I'd like to add are functions calls to a static class. This would immensely help with chaining events. I've looked for documentation on all visual elements in the unity graph view but could not find it anywhere.

The current data a node holds is as follows

```
public class DialogueNode : Node {
public string GUID;
public string DialogueText;
public string AnimationName;
public bool EntryPoint = false;
}
```

Node links:

```
public class NodeLinkData{
public string BaseNodeGuid;
public string PortName;
public string TargetNodeGuid;
}
```

Looks like this

[image: node view]

Is it possible to add a class->function element to the node? I've tried delegates, actions, and UnityEvents and UnityActions or just have not used them correctly.

I know this exists in the context of animations

Currently it is saved as a scriptable object as following

```
public class DialogueContainer : ScriptableObject{
public List<NodeLinkData> NodeLinks = new List<NodeLinkData>();
public List<DialogueNodeData> DialogueNodeData = new List<DialogueNodeData>();}
```

[image]

Comment: both `UnityEvent` and `AnimationEvent` only take **instance** methods if set via the Inspector ... the only way to register static methods (to `Unityevent` .. not sure if for `AnimationEvent` it can be done at all) is via code on runtime

Comment: I see, so is it possible to create fields that hold references to instance methods? I had another solution ready to just put # in the text and check the string on every dialogue update, but it is harder to organize

Comment: yes e.g. `UnityEvent` is such a field it's a little bit unclear though what exactly we are dealing with here .. is this a ScriptableObject? Because getting scene references into ScriptableObjects is not that simple

Comment: Yes it is, I've added the object in the edit just now. Do you believe then it is worth it integrating that element into it or should I just continue calling the functions through strings?